# A problem related to a self-defined function

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, symbols

```
ABCDSeries[x0_] = Module[{x=x0, s1, s2, s3, str, tmp},
s1 = "R";
s2 = "C";
s3 = "L";
str = StringTake[SymbolName[t], 1];
tmp = Which[str=="R", x, str=="C", 1/(I*W*x), str=="L", (I*W*x)];
tmp
];
```

Code Above is used for generate the impedence for circuit analysis

There are three types of input: Resistor R, Capacitor C and Inductor L

And the output of function is `R`, `1/(I W C)` and `I W L`, respectively.

The line `str = StringTake[SymbolName[t], 1];` is used so as if we input `Ls`,

then the function will output `I W Ls`.

However, I type `ABCDSeries[Ls]` and receive `x`, not `I W Ls`.

I have no idea how to fix it. I think maybe the problem is related to local variable

How can I solve the problem, thanks for your help

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Define your function with a `:=` instead of a `=`.  Also, when you define `str` it refers to some variable `t` -  if you change that to `x` or `x0` it works better.

Comment: But one more thing, if `Ls` is defined to be a number instead of just a symbol, you will get an error.

Comment: I've done some changes (`j`->`I`, w->`W`, `ab` ->`a b`) in your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[ABCDSeries];
ABCDSeries[x0_Symbol] := Module[{ str},
   str = StringTake[SymbolName[x0], 1];
   Switch[str,
    "R", x0,
    "C", 1/(I*W*x0),
    "L", (I*W*x0)
    ]
];


ABCDSeries[Ls]
```

> ```
> i Ls W
> ```

---

I put there `x0_Symbol` since `SymbolName` is not `HoldFirst`, if you need to have this function working for `Ls` where `Ls` may have a value, then `SetAttributes` `HoldFirst` to your function and change to `SymbolName @ Unevaluated @ x0`.

Search documentation for references to those things to understand what is going on. Moreover, what you need to read about:

- [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

Comment: Note also that Kuba has removed unnecessary temporary variables and used `Switch` rather than `Which`. These are nice enhancements to your original code.